# When making a game using libgdx the program immediately closes when being run

Tags: java, libgdx

The problem is similar to my last question, but some of the errors are fixed.

The file:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

OrthographicCamera cam;
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;

GameMap gameMap;


@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    cam.update();

    gameMap = new GameMapImpl();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1);
    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
    cam.update();
    gameMap.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    gameMap.render(cam,batch);
}


@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();

}
}
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpriteBatch.end must be called before begin.
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.begin(SpriteBatch.java:169)
at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:38)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
```

Comment: Of course, before asking, you read the error message and you tried to figure out what was going on? Then you tried to google the error to have more details?

Comment: Yeah, I've looked it up, but none of the answers I got solved the problem

Comment: yeah, ive tried looking up `SpriteBatch.end must be called before begin.` and the answers i got weren't helping

Comment: It is a good habit to show what you tried to solve the issue before asking.

Comment: What answers did you find, and how did you try to apply them to your case, and where did that go wrong? Without this information, we're liable to give you the very same answers you've previously found unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is telling you exactly what the problem is...

`SpriteBatch.end` must be called before begin.

The `render()` method code you have shared calls `batch.begin()` then `batch.end()`.  But at some point before you are calling `render()`, you are probably calling `batch.begin()`.  So then render is calling `batch.begin()` a second time and giving you that error.

In other words, you are probably calling `batch.begin()` twice in a row.

So find out where you are calling `batch.begin()` previously, and call `batch.end()` to close it.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Pikalek - I was on my phone on a train when I wrote it...

Comment: Your welcome! Given the circumstances you did better than I would have.